# create file format PDF/A

Tags: pdf

I have a code made with iTextSharp 4.1.2.0 that produce PDF/A (PDFXConformance = PdfWriter.PDFA1B) but now I am developing with iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 that not allowed that conformance and only produce PdfWriter.PDFX1A2001. My question is, this conformance are similar ? In otherwise, why iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 not enabled for PDFA1B. Thanks in advance Carlos

Comment: There is a separate assembly `itextsharp.pdfa` which contains an explicit `PdfAWriter` class which accepts `PdfAConformanceLevel` values `PDF_A_1A`, `PDF_A_1B`, `PDF_A_2A`, `PDF_A_2B`, `PDF_A_2U`, `PDF_A_3A`, `PDF_A_3B`, and `PDF_A_3U`. Have you tested that class yet?

Comment: Hello mkl, I have tested that, but I don't know how it's used. I don't find where this options appear, itextsharp.pdfa.iTextSharp.text.pdf in wich namespace ?

Comment: See [this Visual Studio screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWY3W.png).

Comment: I´m doing that (copier.PDFXConformance = (int)PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B) but when I open PDF with Adobe Acrobat, It say Standrd PDF/X-1:2001 ISO:ISO 15930-1, not PDF/A. I don't know if PDF/X-1:2001 comply with PDF/A conformance

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: here it is https://indise.com.ar/mqST/Gestion/Files_Site/code.jpg

Comment: As mentioned before, there is the separate assembly `itextsharp.pdfa` for PDF/A handling. Originally you didn't show your code and only mentioned *producing PDF/A*, so I thought you were using a `PdfWriter` and only mentioned the `PdfAWriter` to switch to. In your code image I see you actually use a `PdfCopy`. Thus, you should obviously switch to using a `PdfACopy`.

Comment: That being said, I think you have incorrect assumptions here. Already with iTextSharp 4.x your code only created PDF/A documents (if at all) if the source document (imported with the `PdfReader`) already was PDF/A (or nearly so). Otherwise it merely makes your result file *claim* that it is a PDF/A but a PDF/A checker will quickly reject it.

Comment: Thank you so much mkl, I will try anew using itextsharp.pdfa